# Get form parameters from a post request using spray/scala

Tags: scala, post, akka, spray

I'm really new with all this Scala/Spray. With some testing I was able to get parameters from a Get request using the parameters function. However I'm trying to fetch some parameters sent from a POST request on the body of the request. It seems like parameters function is unable to fetch those values.

As an example, I'm trying to get this values "name=john&lastname=smith" from the post request body. What is the best option to get these values?

Thank you

Comment: would you be able to use Request.QueryString("name") ?

Comment: This won't work if the parameter isn't in the query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the [`parameters`](https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/Parameter-Filters) directive only handles things actually in the query-string and not parameters in the body of the request.  To get things out of the body, you'll need to use the `content` directive and then [unmarshal](https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/Marshalling-Unmarshalling) the content.

This [spray-user thread](http://groups.google.com/group/spray-user/browse_thread/thread/a59ce32d5e7725a1/fba18fe741b079f6?lnk=gst&q=post%20parameters#fba18fe741b079f6) may be helpful, as it includes some unmarshalling code doing precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: FYI, the `content` directive was recently renamed into `entity`. Also, as the other answer says, there's the `formFields` directive which allows to extract data from POST data.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Form-Field-Filters] to extract parameters from POSTs

[Form-Field-Filters] https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/Form-Field-Filters

Answer (score 0):

As of recent Spray versions, you need to use the `Unmarshaller` for `FormData`.